# DateObject granularity conversion

Tags: date-and-time, conversion

Is there a way to convert the `DateObject` whose `FullForm` is:

```
date1 = DateObject[List[2019,9,14,0,0,0],"Instant","Gregorian",-7.`]
```

into the following `DateObject`:

```
date2 = DateObject[List[2019,9,14],"Day","Gregorian",-7.`]
```

My list has `DateObject`s with `"Instant"` granularity, but I need to use `Cases` to pick out elements from the same day.  I seem to have missed in the documentation how to do this... Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`DateObject` itself can be used for this:

```
date1 // FullForm
```

> `` DateObject[List[2019,9,14,0,0,0],"Instant","Gregorian",-7.`] ``

```
DateObject[date1, "Day"] // FullForm
```

> `` DateObject[List[2019,9,14],"Day","Gregorian",-7.`] ``