# Reduce granularity and remove options from a DateObject

Tags: date-and-time, version-13.1

I have a `DateObject` with lots of granularity and additional specifications, such as the following e.g.:

```
dateFull = 
 DateObject[
  List[2022, 7, 18, 14, 0, 0],
  "Instant", "Gregorian", 0, "SmearedUTC",   
  List["DateTime", ":", "Millisecond"]
 ]
```

I would like to find a function `f` such that `f[dateFull]` returns `DateObject[List[2022, 7, 18], "Day"]`. This makes comparing dates easier as I can use functions such as `Complement`, `DeleteDuplicates` etc. when I am only concerned with the `"Day"` granularity.

In v13 I used to do this with `DateObject[dateFull, "Day"]` (see also  [DateObject granularity conversion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/206249/27951)), but **in v13.1 it now returns the CalendarType ("Gregorian") as well** i.e.: `DateObject[List[2022, 7, 18], "Day", "Gregorian", 0]`.

Doing something like `f = DateObject[DateString[#, {"ISODate"}], "Day"]&` would work, but it feels ugly/hacky as it seems to imply that I would be better off working with Strings instead of DateObjects. (Indeed, given the ever evolving output of `DateObject` that may well be the case: if memory serves, `DateObject[x, "Day"]` behaviour was also different in v12. It seems like Wolfram is not quite happy with their dates behaviour.)

Comment: Is the `"Gregorian", 0` bit breaking any code?  You can do something like `DateObject[dateFull, "Day"][[;; 2]]` which works in v12 through 13.1 from what I can tell

Comment: @Jason.B yes sadly it is causing breaks. eg. Complement[
{
DateObject[List[2022,7,18],"Day"],
DateObject[List[2022,7,19],"Day"]
},
{DateObject[List[2022,7,18],"Day","Gregorian",0.`]}
]

Thanks I will try DateObject[dateFull, "Day"][[;; 2]]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got in touch with the Wolfram technical team about this and they have suggested :

```
timeZoneApproach=DateObject[#, "Day", TimeZone -> None]&;

FullForm[timeZoneApproach[dateFull]] (* DateObject[List[2022,7,18],"Day"] *)
```

The suggestion from @Jason.B is about 2 times faster on my machine, but you run the risk that the DateObject function might return the position of `List` and `"Day"` differently in future upgrades.

For completeness:

```
partApproach = DateObject[#, "Day"][[;; 2]] &;

pA = partApproach[dateFull]; // RepeatedTiming (*{0.0000198191,Null}*)
tZ = timeZoneApproach[dateFull]; // RepeatedTiming (*{0.0000387157,Null}*)

pA === tZ (*True*)
```